# Opening links from readme preview in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

If I open a readme.md file with a link in it like this:

```
The Code on [Bitbucket](https://some-url.de).
```

I see it in the preview within PhpStorm like this:

> The Code on [Bitbucket](https://some-url.de).

And if I click on the link in the preview I get this message:

[image]

As if my PhpStorm doesn't know what to do. Unfortunately I can't find anything about this on the internet.

Can someone enlighten me or give me a hint how to fix this?

*PhpStorm Version: (PhpStorm 2018.1 Build #PS-181.4203.565)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RUBY-21346](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-21346) is fixed in 2018.1.2; please consider upgrading PhpStorm and *Markdown Support* plugin to the most recent versions